# Reuse Object Creation Code With Entity Framework - Project to new class querying only the required columns

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6.1

Can the `select new MobileTeamModel` be refactored into a reusable method and still be read by Entity Framework?  I have quite a bit of requests that need this same data and would like to reuse it but I know Entity Framework complains about this type of stuff.

```
  var teams = new MobileListResponse<MobileTeamModel>
            {
                List = (from e in _divisionsRepository.DataContext.DivisionTeams.Where(@where.Expand())
                    orderby e.Team.Name
                    select new MobileTeamModel
                    {
                        Id = e.Id,
                        Name = e.Team.Name,
                        Status = e.Status,
                        Paid = e.Paid,
                        Division = e.Division.Name,
                        City = e.Team.TeamAddress.Address.City,
                        StateRegion =
                            e.Team.TeamAddress.Address.StateRegionId.HasValue
                                ? e.Team.TeamAddress.Address.StateRegion.Name
                                : null
                    }).ToList()
            };
```

**EDIT**

The idea is to implement the `select new MobileTeamModel { ... }` in a reusable way, while having EF only query the required columns.

Comment: Can you explain what you want to do in a better way?

Comment: I thought I described it quite well, I want to pull the select new MobileTeamModel in stay a different method and be able to reuse it in another query if needed without pulling all columns for that entity.

Comment: Well, with this comment I understand it now. I read it thrice and din't make a lot of sense...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply have to add a constructor or a factory (static method that return a `MobileTeamModel`) and receives a `Team`.

Then you can make a simpler query like this:

```
select new MobileTeamModel(e.Team)  // parametreized constructor
```

or this

```
select MobileTeamModel.FromTeam(e.Team) // factory
```

Finallyyou can use something like [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com) or [ValueInjecter](http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/) to project the data returned by the query to another class by using conventions or mapping.

*NOTE: I can't see how your clasees look like, but this is the basic idea.*

**EDIT: getting EF to query only the necessary columns**

As for your comment, you want to reuse the construction part, and have EF only query the required columns, and not he whole entities.

Another good explanation here: [Los Techies. Efficient querying with LINQ, AutoMapper and Future queries](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2014/03/11/efficient-querying-with-linq-automapper-and-future-queries/)

To do so you must use Automapper, with [Queryable Extensions](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Queryable-Extensions).

WHen you use this extensions, you can use a mapping from a query result to the destination class, and have EF only query the mapped columns.

Comment: Wouldnt that take all properties of e.Team instead of just the properties I want?

Comment: It was not clear at all in your question. You should re-estate it in a more clear way.

Answer (score 1):

Probably a nice extension method:

```
public static class MobileTeamModelExtensions
{
  public static IEnumerable<MobileTeamModel> ToMobileTeamModels
    (this IQueryable<DivisionTeam> instance)
  {
    var result = instance.Select(e => 
      select new MobileTeamModel
                {
                    Id = e.Id,
                    Name = e.Team.Name,
                    Status = e.Status,
                    Paid = e.Paid,
                    Division = e.Division.Name,
                    City = e.Team.TeamAddress.Address.City,
                    StateRegion =
                        e.Team.TeamAddress.Address.StateRegionId.HasValue
                            ? e.Team.TeamAddress.Address.StateRegion.Name
                            : null
                }).ToList()
    return result;
  }
}
```

So you could:

```
var query = _divisionsRepository.DataContext.DivisionTeams
  .Where(@where.Expand());

var list = query.ToMobileTeamModels();

var query = query.Where(<more where>);

var list2 = query.ToMobileTeamModels();
```